# Python3 str(), bytes, and unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm having trouble with the TYPES involved with this piece of code I wrote.  Ideally I wouldn't pay any mind to encoding types, but sometimes you're forced.

So this is all centered around a directory walk of an NTFS FS on Windows.  Certain characters in file names (unicode, it seems) couldn't be written out to files or printed to the standard windows terminal (yes, I tried "chcp 65001" to print, which didn't work, but I need to write to a standard plain text file anyway)

So I do the following.  As I understand it Python3 (I'm using 3.2.2) is unicode, so str() objects (and all supporting libs) are unicode, so I did this:

```
absfilepath = os.path.join(root, file).encode()
```

thinking utf-8 string would be returned and all is good with the world, but then I was getting errors about implicit type conversions to `str()` when I went to file write or stdout.  So I did the following:

```
hashmap[checksum] = str(absfilepath)
```

(the hashmap is dumped later).

thinking now it's in a native unicode Python3 string...but when I dump it into a file, using this:

```
for key, val in m.items():
    f.write(key + "|" + val + "\n")
```

I still get this in the file:

```
e77bceb64d179377731a94186e56281c|b'K:\Filename'
```

which is indicative as a byte array.

So what am I doing wrong here?  I'm sorry 'non-traditional' characters are in this directory tree, I'd rather them not be there, but they're there.  How do I store them (convert them?) into a manner that can be printed/written in normal plain text (ASCII?) and why is a byte array being returned from my hashmap where I'm clearly storing a standard string?  Dealing with unicode has been a pretty horrific experience for me.

Comment: It's a good idea to read [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to fix the different terms in your mind. The problem here is that the internal representation of strings in Python is just a sequence of code points. When you encode, you don't have characters anymore, you just have bytes which may be decoded back to unicode code points.

Comment: Ok, what you're saying makes sense.  Seems I was a good bit confused as to what encode() did.  I will read this article, thank you!

Comment: When working with filenames in Python 3, always make sure you pass `str`s.  It looks like you're unnecessarily encoding. On the console front, this module: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console provides full Unicode support on the Windows console

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the `str.encode()` function.  Definitely will change that.  Thanks for the tip for unicode support in Windows term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
absfilepath = os.path.join(root, file).encode()
```

`os.path.join()` returns a string, `str.encode()` converts the string to a bytes object, so `absfilepath` contains a bytes object.

```
hashmap[checksum] = str(absfilepath)
```

When you call `str()` on a bytes object, the bytes object is *not* decoded but instead a string representation is created:

```
>>> str(b'K:\Filename')
"b'K:\\\\Filename'"
>>> str(b'K:\Filename') == repr(b'K:\Filename')
True
```

So your dictionary now contains lots of `"b'some-bytes-string'"` strings.

The “fix” is simple: Just don’t encode the strings you get from `os.path.join`.

---

If you get errors while writing the strings out to the file, then consider specifying an explicit encoding when *opening* the file in text mode:

```
with open('some_file', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    …
```

Then Python will automatically write strings correctly.

Alternatively, to be completely safe, you can also open the file in binary mode and write the encoded strings instead:

```
with open('some_file', 'bw') as f:
    value = key + "|" + val + "\n"
    f.write(value.encode()) # write a bytes object
```

But as long as you are *within* Python, you don’t need to worry about special characters inside the string objects. Python can handle them; it’s just the output devices that typically fail (e.g. printing to the console).

Comment: Ok, looks like i misunderstood the concept of str.encode() entirely.  I thought it gave me a str() object which represented a unicode string, not the raw byte array of it.  So if a certain unicode char was 2 bytes, after .encode() I would need to advance index by 2 to get to next "char" ?  Anyway, so looks like I either have to change the source (filenames) or change the the file encoding to unicode-8 or something which will handle them.  Alternatively I could maybe (?) use regex (which will be slow as heck I'm guessing) to find/replace non-ascii chars?  Any simple way to filter non-ascii out?

Answer (score 2):

You encoded your unicode string:

```
absfilepath = os.path.join(root, file).encode()
#                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

This produces a bytestring. Either don't encode, or when storing the paths in your `hashmap` *decode* again:

```
hashmap[checksum] = absfilepath.decode()
```

Comment: Uhm, [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)’s default parameter value is `'utf-8'`…

Comment: Wait, what? A *sane default*? Roight, I had that confused with the `open()` command default for `encoding`.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood encode().  Though if I try something like this (after I stored it like this: `hashmap[checksum] = absfilepath.decode()`), I still may get an error, right?
`print(hashmap[checksum])`
Because it'll be in unicode again in the map and the output device (term, file, w.e), may not be able to handle it and kick it back?

Comment: @Syndacate: so why not encode when printing? Or use the `ascii()` function to produce ASCII-safe debugging output to print.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  I didn't even know about this function, it's probably my best bet I reckon, even if it does print it out weird like "\u1234" which makes it harder to post-process later with scripting - either that or I store in binary or utf-8 as somebody else suggested this way it could be read later.  Opening a file as UTF-8 and printing with ascii() may solve both, especially if I use Python (with Unicode support) to post-process the UTF-8 file later.  Thanks for your input!!

Comment: @Syndacate: I was talking about the output to your console for debugging purposes. If you need to communicate with another program, consider using something like JSON or python pickles, depending on your use cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  How does JSON fix anything?  It's just ASCII encoded, no?  Python pickles, though, that's a good idea for later post processing - or I can just write out to UTF-8 file, guess either works.

Comment: @Syndacate: JSON is an interchange format, so if you are trying to transfer data from one application to another (or to itself via file storage), then it is an option. It encodes lists, maps (dictionaries), strings (full unicode), floats, integers, booleans and nulls.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Yeah, but it's an ASCII encoding, right?  Which means it shares the inherent limitations of not being able to put Unicode characters in it, no?

Comment: @Syndacate: no, JSON uses UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 (UTF-8 being the default). Python's `json` implementation produces *ASCII-safe* output, because you are also allowed to use `\uhhhh` escapes in JSON strings to express any codepoint; Python uses that to express non-ASCII codepoints.

Comment: @Syndacate: The receiver then decodes the JSON again back to Python `unicode` strings or the local Unicode equivalent for other languages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, I see.  Thanks for the explanation.